# Extra unwanted space when setting CSS height and vertical scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a `post` item that can receive comments (that are appended to the bottom of the post).

I'm making a modal for my post that so far with HTML/CSS below. I would like to be able to keep adding comments up until a certain height of the entire post (with comments), at which point the scroll bar will show up.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="post-modal hidden"> 
  <span class="remove-modal glyphicon glyphicon-remove btn-sm"></span>
  <div class="post"> </div> <!-- Post is this div-->
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.post-modal {
    position: fixed;
    width: 655px;
    height: 600px;
    right: 0;
    top: 75px;
    left: 289px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

My problem now is that with a set height for the container `.post-modal` `div`, if my post+comments height are less than the height I set, then there is extra space at the bottom. However, the scroll situation does work if I keep adding comments until the height is reached/exceeded, since I've set the scroll and height for the parent container.

How would you go about accomplishing this without the extra space? Appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `min-height` and `max-height` to get rid of the extra space.

```
.post-modal {
    position: fixed;
    width: 655px;
    min-height: 100px;
    max-height: 600px;
    right: 0;
    top: 75px;
    left: 289px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Nope. I had no idea it was that easy -____- Thanks!

Comment: No problem :)
If you have any further questions do not hesitate and ask them with a code example like you did. I am glad that I could help you.